# Find and List File Names Augment to Include Subfolders

Tags: vba, excel

I have two codes. One will search and name every folder within a directory. The other will list the files and file names within a single folder. I am not proficient enough with VBA to figure this out, so  I need StackOverflow!

Here is the File Name Listing program:

```
Sub Example1()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("\\fc8fsp01\litho_recipe_amat_data")
    i = 1
'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'print file name
        Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
    'print file path
        Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Path
        i = i + 1
Next objFile
End Sub
```

Here is the second code that will navigate sub-folders to write folder names:

```
Option Explicit

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim searchfolders As Variant
Dim FileSystemObject

    Sub ListOfFolders()
        Dim LookInTheFolder As String

        i = 1
        LookInTheFolder = "\D: ' As you know; you should modificate this row.
        Set FileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        For Each searchfolders In FileSystemObject.GetFolder(LookInTheFolder).SubFolders
            Cells(i, 1) = searchfolders
            i = i + 1
            SearchWithin searchfolders
        Next searchfolders

    End Sub

Sub SearchWithin(searchfolders)
        On Error GoTo exits
    For Each searchfolders In FileSystemObject.GetFolder(searchfolders).SubFolders
        j = UBound(Split(searchfolders, "\"))
        Cells(i, j) = searchfolders
        i = i + 1
        SearchWithin searchfolders
        Next searchfolders
exits:
End Sub
```

I need a code that will search all sub folders and list all files contained. Please help D:

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of speed issues when some of the folders I was accessing were present on a network drive, I wrote a little VBA program that uses the Windows Shell `dir` command.  With the proper arguments, this will return all the files in the base directory; as well as all the subfolders and files and so forth.  I have it write the results to a text file, which I then read into Excel for further processing.

Compared with using VBA's DIR or the FSO, this ran about five times faster when the files were on a network drive -- not so noticeable when on the local computer -- but I present it as another approach.

You must set a reference to `Windows Script Host Object Model`.
`sDrive` and `sBasePath` are used to set the starting folder name.
`sFileList` is where the results will be written into a text file.

The `/S` argument Displays files in specified directory and all subdirectories.
The `/B` argument results in omitting heading information and summary

If you run `CMD.EXE` and look for help on the `dir` command, you will see an explanation of the other arguments.

---

```
Public sDrive As String
Public sBasePath As String
Public Const sFileList As String = "C:\Users\Ron\FileList.txt"
Option Explicit
Sub GetDirTree()
    Dim WSH As WshShell
    Dim lErrCode As Long

Set WSH = New WshShell
lErrCode = WSH.Run("cmd.exe /c dir """ & sDrive & sBasePath & """/B /S >" & sFileList, 0, True)
If lErrCode <> 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Error in GetDirTree: Error Number: " & CStr(lErrCode))
    Stop
End If

End Sub
```

---

Comment: I am constantly tripping the error code. I cant tell this is clearly the better option especially since I am trying to map a network drive, but I am having trouble executing.

Comment: I referenced Windows Script Host Model Object. I am certain that I am forgetting some important step. You had mentioned that this will write to an independant text file. Is there any way that I should be placing or referencing a blank text file?

Comment: @CodingNovice  Just enter a file name in place of the one I used in the example.  It would help if you posted the code you are actually using, and the arguments for the drive/folder paths, and the actual error code.

Comment: @CodingNovice Also, you should ensure that the shell command works properly from the `cmd` dialog window.  If it doesn't work there, it won't work in your macro.

Comment: I did check in cmd and it does seem to work. At least the diologue box spits out a large array of data. I am getting the error: "Error in GetDirTree: Error Number:1"

Comment: I am only changing the file path in the code. I tried it with my U drive, and also a shared drive

Comment: It sounds like you did not designate a file for output of the command.

Comment: @CodingNovice It seems you did not check the **entire** code line in the cmd box -- only the `dir` command but not the redirection to the outp[ut file.  If you had done this in its entirety, there should have been nothing in the dialog box -- all of the output should have gone to the file you designated to receive it.  Most likely, you did not provide a valid path for that text file.  Especially since, if I remember correctly, error code 1 means "the system cannot find the file specified".

Answer (score 1):

This is the function I use to find all files in a directory.

```
Public Function RecursiveDir(colFiles As Collection, _
                      ByVal strFolder As String, _
                      strFileSpec As String, _
                      bIncludeSubfolders As Boolean)

 Dim strTemp As String
 Dim colFolders As New Collection
 Dim vFolderName As Variant

'Add files in strFolder matching strFileSpec to colFiles
 strFolder = TrailingSlash(strFolder)
 strTemp = Dir(strFolder & strFileSpec)
 Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
 colFiles.Add strFolder & strTemp
 strTemp = Dir
 Loop

'Fill colFolders with list of subdirectories of strFolder
 If bIncludeSubfolders Then
     strTemp = Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory)
     Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
       If (strTemp <> ".") And (strTemp <> "..") Then
         If (GetAttr(strFolder & strTemp) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
             colFolders.Add strTemp
         End If
     End If
     strTemp = Dir
 Loop

'Call RecursiveDir for each subfolder in colFolders
 For Each vFolderName In colFolders
     Call RecursiveDir(colFiles, strFolder & vFolderName, strFileSpec, True)
 Next vFolderName
 End If

'Garbage collection
 Set colFolders = Nothing

End Function
```

This function will populate a collection of every file name in a given directory. And if you want you can set the `bIncludeSubfolders` to `True`, and it will recursively search all subfolders within this directory. To use this function, you need the following:

```
Dim colFiles As New Collection ' The collection of files
Dim Path As String ' The parent Directory you want to search
Dim subFold As Boolean ' Search sub folders, yes or no?
Dim FileExt As String ' File extension type to search for
```

Then just set `FileExt = "*.*"` Which will find every file with every file extension. Hopefully this helps a little more.