# Count specific files in folder with excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, excel-2010

I need some help with my excel vba.

First of all let me tell what it should do...

On a network folder there are pdf-files which should be count. 
Folders look like this:

```
X:/Tests/Manufact/Prod_1/Machine/Num/Year/Month/TEST_DDMMYYYY_TIMESTAMP.PDF
X:/Tests/Manufact/Prod_2/Machine/Num/Year/Month/TEST_DDMMYYYY_TIMESTAMP.PDF
X:/Tests/Manufact/Prod_3/Machine/Num/Year/Month/TEST_DDMMYYYY_TIMESTAMP.PDF
```

Also there is a folder for each year and for each month, where the pdfs are sorted based on their date of creation. 
The files counted should be listed in the active sheet as a list with filename and date.
After that I want to count how many pdf-files were created on a specific day between a given time. Should be in a new sheet like

```
Date - Time-Period 1 (0AM-6AM) - Time Period 2 (6AM-10AM) - Time Period 3 (10AM - 12AM)

01.01.2017 - 12PDFs - 17PDFs - 11PDFs
02.01.2017 - 19PDFs - 21PDFs - 5PDFs
```

Maybe there is also a way of memory, so the script does not count all the files again which were already listed before? (Cause there are more than 100k pdfs and it's increasing everyday...)

So... I searched a whole week on the internet for solutions, and I found a few, ending me up with this code:

```
Sub ListFiles()
    Const sRoot     As String = "X:\Tests\Manufact\"
    Dim t As Date

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Columns("A:E")
        .ClearContents
        .Rows(1).Value = Split("File,Date,Day,Time,Size", ",")
    End With

    t = Timer
    NoCursing sRoot
    Columns.AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox Format(Timer - t, "0.0s")
End Sub

Sub NoCursing(ByVal sPath As String)
    Const iAttr     As Long = vbNormal + vbReadOnly + _
          vbHidden + vbSystem + _
          vbDirectory
    Dim col         As Collection
    Dim iRow        As Long
    Dim jAttr       As Long
    Dim sFile       As String
    Dim sName       As String

    If Right(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"

    Set col = New Collection
    col.Add sPath

    iRow = 1

    Do While col.count
        sPath = col(1)

        sFile = Dir(sPath, iAttr)

        Do While Len(sFile)
            sName = sPath & sFile

            On Error Resume Next
            jAttr = GetAttr(sName)
            If Err.Number Then
                Debug.Print sName
                Err.Clear

            Else
                If jAttr And vbDirectory Then
                    If Right(sName, 1) <> "." Then col.Add sName & "\"
                Else
                    iRow = iRow + 1
                    If (iRow And &HFFF) = 0 Then Debug.Print iRow
                    Rows(iRow).Range("A1:E1").Value = Array(sName, _
                                                            FileDateTime(sName), _
                                                            FileDateTime(sName), _
                                                            FileDateTime(sName), _
                                                            FileLen(sName))
                End If
            End If
            sFile = Dir()
        Loop
        col.Remove 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

What it does is counting ALL files in the directorys (So there is something missing telling it to only count PDFs).

It does list the files in my sheet, I'm happy with that part, but it only lists it. I still need the sorting part, so either only let it count day and time period, or let it count/list everything first and afterwards sort and count only the day and time period from the list (I really don't know which one would be better, maybe there is an easy way and a hard one?)

So if any one has a clue how to do that, please let me know, I'm thankful for any help!

Best Regards - Jan

Comment: I was thinking this was as easy as just specifying "*.PDF" in your `Dir` command, but the code you are using is treating files and directories as the same thing, so that would then only look in subfolders with a `.PDF` suffix.  I think the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31482364/6535336) to another question would work better for you.  (You will probably need to change the line which says `strFolder = TrailingSlash(strFolder)` to be `If Right(strFolder, 1) <> "/" Then strFolder = strFolder & "/"`.)

Answer (score 0):

OK I just worked on a similar project not to long ago. I am going to assume something here and you tell me if anything will break the whole system.

1) We can and are allowed to move .PDF files to a sub folder after we process it, or
2) We can and are allowed to rename (even temporary) .PDF files.

3) If we pass a month we do not need to process it any longer, for example today we are in February of 2017, so we stopped processing January 2017 files.

If we can and are allowed to proceed with these assumptions, then to lessen the double work, once a .PDF is processed it could be either moved to a sub folder called Processed Files within that month's folder, and at the end of the month we can return them back, or renamed by appending it with a special tag say "PrOCed" if that string will never ever appear in the file name, and then we can exclude any files in that new folder or with that tag.

I would suggest that you would simply read all the file names into a worksheet and then use Text-to-Columns to get the date and time of the file creation, plus maybe you can use the FileSystemObject to get that info to, and then simply use the Excel Group feature to get the breakdown by day and hour.

Hope this helps, if you need any code example, let me know.

Comment: 1) and 2) Unfortunatelly I'm not allowed to rename/move/copy/change the files in any way, not even temporary.

3) If that would mean the code has to be run latest at 31.01. for january files then this is also not possible, cause there could be a case when no one can run the script in time and we pass 01.02. before running the script.

Some code about the last thing you mentioned woud be intersting, I'm not as deep in the coding as I would like to be, still learning :)

Comment: OK Thanks for confirming the limitations Jan

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.  The following is largely untested
and should really be treated as pseudocode.  Besides it's not
clear that I could give a definitive answer as I've had to make too
many assumptions (ie is Num in the directory just 'Num' or is
it a number, how is TIMESTAMP defined, etc).

I'm assuming that your pdfs will be properly filed in the
correct month folder.
Ie, for example, you won't have
say a month '09' in a '10' folder (this would be an error condition).  If that's the case then
what I'm proposing should work.  Note that I'm also assuming that
the filenames are correct.  If not you can add additional error
processing.  Right now if I find an error in the filename I simply skip it - but
you'll probably want to have it printed out as mentioned in the 
code comments.

The main data structure is a dictionary that should end up having
a day entry (ie key,value) for each day of the month once all the pdfs for that
month have been processed.  The key of this dictionary is a 2 digit
string that represents the day from '01' up to '31' (for the months that
have 31 days).  The value is a 1 dimensional array of length 3.  So a typical
entry could be (20,31,10) which is 20 files for period 1, 31 for period 2 and
10 for period 3.

For each file you process a regular expression that extracts the day and hour only.
I'm assuming that the period hours don't overlap (just makes things easier - ie so
I don't have to bother with minutes).  Once that's extracted I then add to
that days array for the correct time period based on the hour I've found.

You should note that I assume if you've gone through all product directories
for a given month you have now all that months files.  So with all the month
files you can now print out the period counts on a different worksheet for each
day.

I haven't bothered implementing 'SummarizeFilesForMonth' but this should be
relatively straightforward once everything else has been debugged.  This is
the place where you'll iterate through the day keys in the proper order to
print out the period stats.  Other than that there shouldn't have to be any
other additional sorting.

```
Option Explicit

' Gets all files with the required file extension,
' strips off both the path and the extension and
' returns all files as a collection (which might not be
' what you want - ie might want the full path on the 1st sheet)
Function GetFilesWithExt(path As String, fileExt As String) As Collection
  Dim coll As New Collection
  Dim file As Variant
  file = dir(path)

  Dim fileStem As String, ext As String
  Do While (file <> "")
    ext = Right(file, Len(file) - InStrRev(file, "."))
    If ext = fileExt Then
      fileStem = Right(file, Len(file) - InStrRev(file, "\"))
      coll.Add Left(fileStem, Len(file) - 5)
    End If
    file = dir
  Loop

  Set GetFilesWithExt = coll
End Function


' Checks whether a directory exists or not
Function pathExists(path As String)
 If Len(dir(path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
   pathExists = False
 Else
   pathExists = True
 End If
End Function


' TEST_DDMMYYYY_TIMESTAMP is the filename being processed
' assuming TIMESTAMP is hr min sec all concatenated with
' no intervening spaces and all are always 2 digits
Sub UpdateDictWithDayFile(ByRef dictForMonth As Variant, file As String)
 Dim regEx As New RegExp

 ' only extracts day and hour - you'll almost certainly
 ' have to adjust this regular expression to suit your needs
 Dim mat As Object
 Dim Day As String
 Dim Hour As Integer
 regEx.Pattern = "TEST_(\d{2})\d{2}\d{4}_(\d{2})\d{2}\d{2}$"
 Set mat = regEx.Execute(file)
 If mat.Count = 1 Then
   Day = mat(0).SubMatches(0) ' day is a string
   Hour = CInt(mat(0).SubMatches(1)) ' hour is an integer
 Else
   ' Think about reporting an error here using debug.print
   ' i.e., the filename isn't in the proper format
   ' and will not be counted
   Exit Sub
 End If

 If Not dictForMonth.exists(Day) Then
   ' 1 dimensional array of 3 items; one for each time period
   dictForMonth(Day) = Array(0, 0, 0)
 End If

 Dim periods() As Variant
 periods = dictForMonth(Day)

 ' I'm using unoverlapping hours unlike what's given in your question
 Select Case Day
   Case Hour <= 6
    periods(0) = periods(0) + 1
   Case Hour >= 7 And Hour < 10
    periods(1) = periods(1) + 1
   Case Hour >= 10
    periods(2) = periods(2) + 1
   Case Else
     ' Another possible error; report on debug.print
     ' will not be counted
     Exit Sub
 End Select

End Sub


Sub SummarizeFilesForMonth(ByRef dictForMonth As Variant)
  ' This is where you write out the counts
  ' to the new sheet for the month.  Iterate through each
  ' day of the month in 'dictForMonth' and print
  ' out each of pdf counts for the individual periods
  ' stored in the 1 dimensional array of length 3
End Sub


Sub ProcessAllFiles()
 ' For each day of the month for which there are pdfs
 ' this dictionary will hold a 1 dimensional array of size 3
 ' for each
 Dim dictForMonth As Object

 Dim year As Integer, startYear As Integer, endYear As Integer
 Dim month As Integer, startMonth As Integer, endMonth As Integer
 Dim prodNum As Integer, startProdNum As Integer, endProdNum As Integer
 Dim file As Variant
 Dim files As Collection

 startYear = 2014
 startMonth = 1
 endYear = 2017
 endMonth = 2
 startProdNum = 1
 endProdNum = 3

 Dim pathstem As String, path As String
 pathstem = "D:\Tests\Manufact\Prod_"

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim row As Integer
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
 row = 1

 For year = startYear To endYear:
   For month = 1 To 12:
     Set dictForMonth = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

     For prodNum = startProdNum To endProdNum
       If prodNum = endProdNum And year = endYear And month > endMonth Then Exit Sub

       path = pathstem & prodNum & "\Machine\Num\" & year & "\" & Format(month, "00") & "\"
       If pathExists(path) Then
         Set files = GetFilesWithExt(path, "pdf")
         For Each file In files:
           ' Print out file to column 'A' of 'Sheet1'
           ws.Cells(row, 1).Value = file
           row = row + 1
           UpdateDictWithDayFile dictForMonth, CStr(file)
         Next
       End If

     Next prodNum
     SummarizeFilesForMonth dictForMonth
   Next month
 Next year

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, that's great work so far! 
But there are some things we have to solve (cause I messed that up in my post) 

First of all there is this god damn folder structure (I don't like it myself but can't change it) 
Folders exactly look like this:

`X:/Tests/Manufact/{Product}/Machine/{Part}/Year/Month/`
Where {Product} is one of these three names "L450", "L460" or "L510"
And {Part} is in a format like 9P-306-01800-123 but in folders like this:
`{Part} in "L450" can be 9P-306-01800-123, 9P-306-03600-123, 9P-306-11800-123, 9P-306-13600-123`

Comment: `{Part} in "L460" can be 9P-308-01800-123, 9P-308-03600-123, 9P-308-11800-123, 9P-308-13600-123, 9P-308-21800-123, 9P-308-23600-123`
`{Part} in "L510" can be 9P-304-02100-123, 9P-304-02300-123, 9P-304-03400-123, 9P-304-04600-123, 9P-304-12100-123, 9P-304-12300-123, 9P-304-13400-123, 9P-304-14600-123`

The Filename is another thing you wanted to know better, so I looked that up again and it is build exactly like this:
`{Number}_0{Serial}_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.PDF`

Comment: Where {Number} can be one of these 18 numbers 
`5140391, 5140392, 5140393, 5140394, 5140395, 5140396, 5140397, 5140398, 5142485, 5142487, 5142494, 5142762, 5142769, 5142770, 5142821, 5142822, 5144561, 5144562`
And {Serial} is build of four letters and a 6 digit number (AAAA012345)

And there is one more things about the times. 
Originally I planned to count some different things but now seeing this thing in the future I have to count the files between three times like this:

Comment: `11:01PM to 07:00AM (This would be 31.12.16 11:01PM to 01.01.17 07:00AM)`
`07:01AM to 03:00PM (This would be 01.01.17 07:01AM to 01.01.17 03:00PM)`
`03:01PM to 11:00PM (This would be 01.01.17 03:01PM to 01.01.17 11:00PM)`
I assume your script did already do the thing I showed with the minutes ( :00 and :01) mentioned just to be clear here this time. 

Also there is a minimal chance of files from month 02 getting in folder month 01. I think this is very difficult to let the script count these wrong sorted ones somehow, if it can it's super nice, but if it doesn't I would not care about it.

Comment: I hope I thought about all issues now, this is so hard to tell if you don't know that much about how to code it - I'm still learning but this one is (as I've seen now) so much more than I could imagine

Thank you so much for your help, I'm really looking forward to your reply :)

P.S.: Man that 600 Character limit for comments killed me :-D

Comment: Give me a day or two to get back to this.   Will have to divide and conquer on this application - first thing is to be able to iterate through all these directories.

Comment: Any news about this project?

Comment: Sorry completely forgot about it - will look at this tonight.

Answer (score 0):

OK Thanks for confirming the limitations Jan

So then the next option is to build a list of file names in a worksheet that have been processed and pass them, for example if you are using a For Each loop to loop through the files, there will be a test to see if the current name of the file is in the list of processed files, skip it otherwise process it and add its name to the list.

## 3 refers to all the files in a past month. This way we can search for files by date and get new files to process. So all files generated past a certain date (last run date) will be considered new and need to be processed.

Will that work?